# Objective-C: 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I want to set the value of an object for a certain key, but I get this strange error.
I also tried to use setValue instead of setObject and the routenArray2 also got the key in it.

```
NSMutableArray *routenArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *routenArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
abfahrt,@"Abfahrt", ankunft, @"Ankunft", dauer, @"Dauer", route, @"Route", kennung, @"Kennung", nil];

[routenArray addObject:dict];

for (int j = 0; j < routenArray.count; j++) {

    NSNumber *lNumber = [indexArray objectAtIndex:j];
    int l = [lNumber intValue];

    if (l == i) {
          [routenArray2 addObject:[[routenArray objectAtIndex:j] copy]];
    }
}

NSString *kennungString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", k];

for (int i = 0; i < routenArray2.count; i++) {
      [[routenArray2 objectAtIndex:i] setObject:kennungString forKey:@"Kennung"]; //this line is the problem
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get more in detail - the log you get? why can I see a `k` but not the declaration ?

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance' thats the error. k is an integer

Comment: -1 for not including the *exact and complete* error message in the original question, and for not identifying the failing line.

Comment: You're welcome!  It was a very inexpensive lesson.

Comment: @HotLicks because you know nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
[routenArray2 addObject:[[routenArray objectAtIndex:j] mutableCopy]];
```

Instead of

```
[routenArray2 addObject:[[routenArray objectAtIndex:j] copy]];
```

`copy` returns `NSDictionary`, you need `mutableCopy` to return `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: this works, thanks a lot you just finished my diploma project ;)

Comment: Glad to have helped, user3298017

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = (NSMutableDictionary *)[routenArray2 objectAtIndex:i];
[newDict setObject:kennungString forKey:@"Kennung"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try typecasting in assign the value

```
[(NSMutableDictionary *)[routenArray2 objectAtIndex:i] setObject:kennungString forKey:@"Kennung"];
```

Comment: also the same error..